# IntelliJ adding jar dependencies

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a Maven project and I want to add a JAR file as an external dependency to the project.
After clicking 'New' in Project Structure I expect to see an option for "JAR file". Unfortunately, I don't see it. Do you have any idea why or what I can do to add external JAR file as a dependency?

[image]

Comment: Weird. Have you tried adding e.g. a `lib` dir to your project, throwing the jar in there and right-click - add lib/dependency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you're in the wrong tab of project structure settings.

Follow those instructions: [Correct way to add external jars (lib/*.jar) to an IntelliJ IDEA project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project)